# Content filtering of webpage

Tags: python, optimization, html, python-2.x

This is code for filtering the data of webpage, for the web crawler I made for my project. I know python scripts can lag than other languages, but this takes a lot of time when processing even a single page.

I don't want to use any other external libraries for filtering content. Is there any way my current code can be improved to be **cleaner** and **faster**?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import urllib
url='http://designingadam2.wordpress.com'
def content(page,url):#FILTERS THE CONTENT OF THE REMAINING PORTION
    flg=0
    #REMOVES &nsbp LIKE CHARACTERS
    while page.find("&",flg)!=-1:
        page.replace('&nbsp;','')
        start=page.find("&",flg)
        end=page.find(";",start+1)
        if (end-start)<10:  #USED IF HERE TO CNFRM TAGS-->REMOVE IF NOT NEEDED
            pageO=page[:start]
            pageT=page[end+1:]
            page=pageO+pageT
            flg=start+1#TO CONTINUE FROM NEXT POS
        else:
            flg+=1
    flg=0

    #REMOVES CONTENT BETWEEN SCRIPT TAGS
    while page.find("<script",flg)!=-1:
            start=page.find("<script",flg)
            end=page.find("</script>",flg)
            end=end+9
            i,k=0,end-start
            page=list(page)
            while i<k:
                    page.pop(start)
                    i=i+1
            page=''.join(page)
            flg=start

    #REMOVES CONTENT BETWEEN STYLE TAGS
    flg=0
    while page.find("<style",flg)!=-1:
            start=page.find("<style",flg)
            end=page.find("</style>",flg)
            end=end+9
            i,k=0,end-start
            page=list(page)
            while i<k:
                    page.pop(start)
                    i=i+1
            page=''.join(page)
            flg=start

    #REMOVES THE TAGS
    s_list = list(page)
    i,j = 0,0
    while i < len(s_list):
            # find the <
            if s_list[i] == '<':
                while s_list[i] != '>':# and i!=(len(s_list)-1):
                    # remove everything between the < and the >
                    s_list.pop(i)

                # make sure we get rid of the > to
                s_list.pop(i)
            else:
                i=i+1
    #-------------------------------------------------------------------

    #REMOVES WHITESPACES
    s_list="".join(s_list)
    lst=s_list.split()
    #CONVERT TO LOWERCASE
    i=0
    while i<len(lst):
        lst[i]=lst[i].lower()
        i+=1

    #REMOVES DUPLICATES
    lst=list(set(lst))

    #REMOVE COMMON WORDS
    phrase=['to','a','an','the',\
            'for','from','that','their',\
            'i','my','your','you','mine',\
            'we','okay','yes','no','as',\
            'if','but','why','can','now',\
            'are','is','also',',','.',';',\
            ':','?','|','/','\n','\t']

    i=0
    while i<len(lst):
        if lst[i] in phrase:
            lst.pop(i)
        else:
            i+=1
    print lst
    print len(lst)

def pageContent(url):#EXTRACTS HTML CODE
    f = urllib.urlopen(url)
    page = f.read()
    f.close()
    #page=page.replace(u'\xa0', ' ').encode('utf-8','ignore')
    return page

page=pageContent(url)
content(page,url)
```

Please mind the comments. I left it so it could be of some help.

Comment: Obligatory suggestion to read and consider following [the style guide](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). You say "outside libraries" - is the standard library OK?

Comment: Why not external libraries? [BeautifulSoup](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/beautifulsoup4) can be helpful here.

Comment: @jcollado i know about BeautifulSoup but my mentor has told me to do this without using any other libraries.

Comment: @jonrsharpe yeah standard libraries are OK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per my comment, follow [the style guide](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) - for example, there should be whitespace around `=` when assigning, and after commas:

```
i, k = 0, end - start
```

---

`content` is not a good name for your function. You should be more descriptive of what it actually does (perhaps `filter_content`?) and add a docstring providing more information. Throughout your code there are temporary variables with cryptic names (`s_list`? `lst`?) that could be changed to make things much clearer - I was wondering why `flg` isn't Boolean, and it turns out that it isn't actually a flag.

---

Your approach to removing HTML tags (picking through the whole page character by character) is particularly prone to error; what if one of the attributes within a tag contains `'>'`? For a good standard library solution, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/925630/3001761).

---

The conversion to lowercase is, frankly, ludicrous:

```
i=0
while i<len(lst):
    lst[i]=lst[i].lower()
    i+=1
```

you had the whole string (called, confusingly, `s_list`) to hand just two lines beforehand, and

```
s_list = s_list.lower()
```

is so much simpler.

---

As you're making a `set` to remove duplication:

```
lst=list(set(lst))
```

why not keep the set, instead of converting back to `list`, and use it to do the filtering, too? For example, use [`set.difference_update`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.difference_update):

```
>>> words = set('this is a sentence to filter'.split())
>>> words.difference_update(['a', 'to', 'this', 'is'])
>>> words
set(['sentence', 'filter'])
```

---

Your other function could be simplified significantly:

```
def page_content(url):
    with urllib.urlopen(url) as f:
        return f.read()
```

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer. It helped me a lot( especially the HTML tag filter):)